# Spring 3.2.5 error "java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found" for all my controller Unit Test

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit4, spring-test-mvc

I'm trying to write some unit tests for my controllers in a Spring MVC and i have already error for my unit test : "java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found.

my app and conrollers works correcty.

Does anyone have any ideas ?

code controller :

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
@RequestMapping(value="/loginfailed", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String loginerror(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("error", "true");
    return "accueilLogin";

}
}
```

unit test :

```
ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/META-INF/applicationContext-test.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class LoginControllerTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac ;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    System.out.println(wac.getBeanDefinitionNames());

}
@Test
public void testLoginFailed() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/loginfailed")).andDo(print())
    .andExpect(view().name("accueilLogin"));
}
```

spring-security config :

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/accueilLogin*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/register*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/logout*" access="ROLE_USER" /> -->
    <form-login login-page="/accueilLogin" default-target-url="/welcome"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
</http>
```

web.xml config :

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml,
        classpath:/META-INF/applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

request logs:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
     HTTP Method = GET
     Request URI = /loginfailed
      Parameters = {}
         Headers = {}

         Handler:
            Type = null
Resolved Exception:
            Type = null

    ModelAndView:
       View name = null
            View = null
           Model = null

        FlashMap:

MockHttpServletResponse:
          Status = 404
   Error message = null
         Headers = {}
    Content type = null
            Body = 
   Forwarded URL = null
  Redirected URL = null
         Cookies = []
```

the stacktrace :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:39)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ViewResultMatchers$2.match(ViewResultMatchers.java:62)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:148)
at fr.web.LoginControllerTest.testLoginFailed(LoginControllerTest.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:231)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:88)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:174)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Please add a stacktrace.

Comment: I just add the strack trace, thanks

Comment: Let's see your `applicationContext-test.xml` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logs are showing that you are getting a 404

```
Status = 404
```

which means that your handler is not being found.

I'm willing to bet that your `@Controller` isn't being registered. You've loaded your config like so

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/META-INF/applicationContext-test.xml" })
```

Does `applicationContext-test.xml` do a `<component-scan>` on the package that your controller is in? Does it do a `<mvc:annotation-driven>`? If it doesn't, then your application hasn't registered your handler method.

Comment: I forgot statement <context:component-scan base-package="fr.web"/>, she works, thanks for your help. but i dont understand why the application starts even without <coponent-scan..

Comment: @user3096030 Because registering handlers is just a side effect. There are many ways to do it (you also don't necessarily need to do it). Consider accepting the answer unless you have other equestions.