# Spring MVC Test: java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found

Tags: java, spring-mvc, testing, junit, modelandview

I'm novice to all this stuff, writing test for Spring MVC controller and got error above, tried solution provided in 
[Spring 3.2.5 error "java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found" for all my controller Unit Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547922/spring-3-2-5-error-java-lang-assertionerror-no-modelandview-found-for-all-my) - still no luck! Could pls anyone help? Thanks in advance!

let me know if anything else needed on top of code below.

test class:

*(note, that printout of getBeanDefinitionNames() among others returns "homeController" - so I assume controller is found and initialized )*

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={WebDispatcherConfig.class,DataConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class HomeControllerTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac ;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wac.getBeanDefinitionNames()));

}

@Test
public void testHome() throws Exception {


    mockMvc
    .perform(get(WebDispatcherConfig.WEBAPP_PREFIX))
    .andExpect(view().name(HomeController.HOME))
    .andExpect(model().attributeExists(WebDispatcherConfig.PREFIX_NAME));
}

}
```

web context config class:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("io.github.d2edev.mywebapp.web")
public class WebDispatcherConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
public static final String WEBAPP_PREFIX="/web";
public static final String PREFIX_NAME="wepbrefix";

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    return resolver;
}



@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

}

controller (note it's already in package reflected in @ComponentScan in config class above):

```
package io.github.d2edev.mywebapp.web;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import io.github.d2edev.mywebapp.config.WebDispatcherConfig;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {
public static final String HOME="home";

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Model model){
    model.addAttribute(WebDispatcherConfig.PREFIX_NAME, WebDispatcherConfig.WEBAPP_PREFIX);
    return HOME;
}
```

}

stacktrace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.fail(AssertionErrors.java:39)
at org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertTrue(AssertionErrors.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ViewResultMatchers$2.match(ViewResultMatchers.java:68)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc$1.andExpect(MockMvc.java:171)
at test.web.HomeControllerTest.testHome(HomeControllerTest.java:52)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved!
Reason is that in my real app servlet is mapped to "/web" and HomeController to "/" which results that controller serves requests to "/web".
So I provided same "/web" address for GET request in controller test class, but when we create MockMvc, as I understood, we can't make mapping like we do in app init class, so "test" controller was waiting for my request at "/".
To make it work, I should either explicitly put

```
.perform(get("/"))
```

or make on-fly remapping with additional code like proposed here:

[MockMvc WebAppConfiguration: Load servlet mappings in web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25270135/mockmvc-webappconfiguration-load-servlet-mappings-in-web-xml)

Thanks!